# Saving sheet to a location using the title of the sheet to name the file

Tags: vba, excel

I have written for a button -

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim path As String
    Dim filename1\ As String

    path = C:\Users\Barb\Desktop\demo\"
    filename1 = Range("C4").Text
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename1=path & filename1 & ".xlsx", 
    FileFormatxlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

How can I tell it when saving the sheet to use the title of the sheet tab

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about the `ActiveSheet`, change:

```
filename1 = Range("C4").Text
```

to:

```
filename1 = ActiveSheet.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

something like, for example:

```
filename1 = sheets(1).name
```

Or

```
filename1 = activesheet. name
```

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the sheet name.